# How to make the player move in the direction it is facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this game in unity that is still in development. My movement code so far can move the player with arrow keys. I also have a feature to move the player with your mouse. It turns the player on how it is facing. Let's say the player is facing left. If I click on the up arrow key, it still moves forward. I want to move the player in the direction it is facing.

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

 public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

 public float distance = 5f;

 public Transform playerCam;

 void FixedUpdate () {
  transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, 
  Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.y, transform.localEulerAngles.z);
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
  {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.x--;
      this.transform.position = position;
  }
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
  {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.x++;
      this.transform.position = position;
  }
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
  {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.z++;
      this.transform.position = position;
  }
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
  {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.z--;
      this.transform.position = position;
  }
  if (Input.GetKey("W"))
  {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.z++;

      this.transform.position = position;
  }
  if (Input.GetKey("S"))
  {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.z--;

      this.transform.position = position;
  }
  if (Input.GetKey("A"))
  {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.x--;

      this.transform.position = position;
  }
  if (Input.GetKey("D"))
  {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.x++;

      this.transform.position = position;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Comment: Thank you, but I need to know how to move the player, not look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `transform.forward` to get the direction the player is facing.

It will always be a unit vector, so if you just want to move the position by exactly one unit in the player's forward direction, you can just add it to `transform.position`:

```
if (Input.GetKey("W")) 
{
    this.transform.position += this.transform.forward;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It really helped but let's say I want to make the player move backward in the direction it is facing? I tried  this.transform.position += this.transform.backward

Comment: There is no `transform.backward`. You have to use `this.transform.position -= this.transform.forward` instead.